# how to pass environment variables to terraform modules

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i am relatively new to terraform and looking for some help here! i want to refer a module and have it deployed across multiple AWS regions. I also want to pass few environment variables into the module something like this:

```
module "aws-eu-central-1" {
  source="git::https://<git-repo-url>"
  export TF_VAR_REGION="eu-central-1"
  export TF_VAR_TABLE_NAME="euc-accounts"
  export TF_VAR_ES_ENDPOINT="euc-elasticsearch"
  export TF_VAR_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
}

module "aws-eu-west-1" {
  source="git::https://<git-repo-url>"
  export TF_VAR_REGION="eu-west-1"
  export TF_VAR_TABLE_NAME="euw-accounts"
  export TF_VAR_ES_ENDPOINT="euw-elasticsearch"
  export TF_VAR_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
}

module "aws-eu-west-2" {
  source="git::https://<git-repo-url>"
  export TF_VAR_REGION="eu-west-2"
  export TF_VAR_TABLE_NAME="euw-accounts"
  export TF_VAR_ES_ENDPOINT="euw-elasticsearch"
  export TF_VAR_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
}
```

i want my source code to get deployed across these regions and want to pass the environment variables to the module. how this can be done? thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass the variable to the terraform executable:

```
TF_VAR_REGION=eu-central-1 terraform plan
```

That creates the REGION variable which you can then pass to the module:

```
module "aws-eu-central-1" {
  source="git::https://<git-repo-url>"
  region="{var.REGION}"
}
```

Comment: thanks @victor m, i am doing that if i want to pass same variables ( with same value) but in my case i want to pass different values of REGION, ES_ENDPOINT and TABLE_NAME to the module so that i can run the terraform in one go rather than exporting the variables multiple times.. is there any way it can be done easily? Thanks,

Comment: this is what i tried but, no luck. my shall script contains:    `TF_VAR_env=$ENVIRONMENT aws-vault exec $2 -- terraform $1
   TF_VAR_eucentral1=eu-central-1 aws-vault exec $2 -- terraform $1` and added this in the terraform `module "awsviz-eu-central-1" {
  source="git::https://<repo-url>"
  REGION="{var.eucentral1}"
  TABLE_NAME="{var.env}-config-accounts"
  ES_ENDPOINT="{var.env}-aws-elasticsearch"
}
module "awsviz-eu-west-1" {
  source="git::https://<repo-url>"
  REGION="{var.euwest1}"
  TABLE_NAME="{var.env}-config-accounts"
  ES_ENDPOINT="{var.env}-aws-elasticsearch"
}`